# js dataTable yadcf Keeping the filter values

Tags: javascript, .net, datatables, yadcf

I'm using yadcf plugin on jquery dataTables.  I'm looking at 
yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html 
and say you click on the first column filter.  It shows you a list of options.  You click on Other Browsers Eng'.  It transforms the table appropriately.  You click on the filter again to see the same list of options.

For me, when I transform the table through AJAX, I also transform the filters, which is a good thing.  I mean you now see what else is available to you... unless you click on your original filter, then you have to erase that filter to go back to see your original list of options.

How do I keep the original list of options in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the server side setup for your datatables then its up to you to maintain the list of available options in the yadcf filters. In adtion to your data of the table that you send from your server back to your client you need to set the filter values into the `yadcf_data_0` / `yadcf_data_1` / etc...

See more info about the server side setup on the showcase code snippet in the [bottom of the page](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html)

If its not the server side setup but rather a DOM / AJAX and you want your filters to be populated by only the available values from the table, then you should use the [cumulative_filtering](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L237) option of the yadcf

p.s

I'm the author of [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf)

Comment: Cool.  I've added `"yadcf_data_1"` to my JSON and the values did load into the filter, but whenever I attempt to use any filter now, the DataTable gets stuck on processing.  I'm getting an error saying `12:30:59.338 TypeError: plugins[table_selector_jq_friendly] is undefined1 jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:2939:10` Any idea what that could be?

Comment: grab latest yadcf version from github, reproduce the error and open a new issue with all the details (error code line number with the error) on github, and wait for a fix. and if the current question was answered than accept the answer.